# C function typedef: defining function without parameter list

Tags: c, typedef, function-declaration

I have program that has dozens (maybe over 100) functions with same parameter list and return type. I also may want to add parameter to those functions. So, is there any way to define those functions with `typedef` prototype (with parameter list)?

example: I have dozens of functions `int f1 (int, int)` so i have dozens of declarations like:

```
int f1 (int x, int y){...}
int f2 (int x, int y){...}
....
int fn(int x, int y){...}
```

I'd like to define those something like:

```
typedef int functiontype(int x, int y);
functiontype f1{...}
...
functiontype fn{...}
```

So when I need to upgrade those functions (eg. with new parameter z) I only have to upgrade the typedef sentence. 
Is that somehow possible?

Comment: You probably should be generating your functions, rather than writing them by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a preprocessor macro like this

```
#define FUNCTION(function) int function(int x, int y)

/* prototype */
FUNCTION(f1);
/* definition */
FUNCTION(f1)
{
    /* do something here, for example */
    return y - x;
}
```

Comment: Damn, 10 seconds isn't a lot.

Comment: @Quentin it isn't a little either, and it's strange that you chose the same name for the macro, but it's of course very unlikely that you saw my answer before posting yours.

Comment: Well, that's true. But wouldn't it kill ctags and other symbol/definition lookup tools? @milleniumbug's idea of using structs for parameters sounds better then.

Comment: @IgorS.K. it could possibly pay off, but it depends on why would the OP want to do this, I can't think of any other way, may be there is.

Comment: It's also possible to `#undef FUNCTION` afterwards.

Comment: Also, 10 seconds to read your answer, ensure it's correct, duplicate it in a new answer, change it a bit all over, and post it ? Man, I wish I could be that fast :p

Answer (score 6):

No, not really. Use a `struct`:

```
typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z; //added
} Params;

int the_function(Params p);
```

That way you avoid breaking source code of functions that declare `z`.

With compound literals, you can even avoid naming the `struct`:

```
the_function((Params){ 2, 5 }); // after adding .z, the source code is unchanged. Its value is 0. Or...
the_function((Params){ .x = 2, .y = 5 }); // named arguments with C99 designated initializers!
```

Comment: Nice. The typedef doesn't make sense though.

Comment: And also, this is an alternate solution, not the answer to the post.

Comment: @iharob Why ? It perfectly answers the question. I can't see where OP specifically asked for macros.

Comment: The OP asked about a function factory, yours is not one. Also, your code will not work with a c compiler. It will work with c++ though, the question is about c.

Comment: @iharob The OP asked for a way to avoid changing code in multiple functions (adding arguments), and this perfectly answers the question. About the C incompatibility, yes, indeed, I forgot the `typedef` for the struct, to make `Params p` work. It is correct now.

Comment: @milleniumbug and I like your solution, it's cleaner and allows more maintainability, but it's just a matter of what the OP wanted. And since your solution is elegant then +1.

Answer (score 3):

Not with a typedef, but you can use a macro :

```
#define FUNCTION(name) int name(int x, int y)

FUNCTION(f1) {
    // ...
}

FUNCTION(f2) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#define STANDARD_FUNCTION(fname) int fname(int x, int y)
STANDARD_FUNCTION(f1) { /*do work; return int; */ }
STANDARD_FUNCTION(f2) { /*do work; return int; */ }
STANDARD_FUNCTION(f3) { /*do work; return int; */ }
```

Then later, when you add a new param, you only have to change:

```
#define STANDARD_FUNCTION(fname) int fname(int x, int y, double newParam)
```